# Replace images one after in different period of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I want to replace `foundImg` with `loadingImg`, for `families` array. The first one after 2sec then the second after 3....

This code replaces them at the same time

```
const loadingImg = require('./assets/25.gif');
const foundImg = require('./assets/done_Icon.png');

class App  extends Component {

 state = {
    families: [
      {id:0, name: "Accident History", duration: 2000, image: loadingImg},
      {id:1, name: "Title Information", duration: 3000, image: loadingImg},
      {id:2, name: "Liens", duration: 5000, image: loadingImg}
    ],
  }

componentDidMount(){
    const newFamilies = this.state.families;
    newFamilies.map(item => { 
      item.image = foundImg;
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({families: newFamilies}),item.duration)       
    })
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding time to  setTimeout function e.g setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);  3000- being  3 seconds shown as 30000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.families.forEach(item => { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        const families = this.state.families.slice();
        const itemFound = families.filter(i => i.id === item.id)[0];
        itemFound.image = foundImg;
        this.setState({families: families})
      }, item.duration)       
    })
}
```

Avoid using map when you don't transform the array. Use foreach instead.